# Tag badges don't need a reason

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, tag-badges

Some badges have a reason associated with them: a link to the post that resulted in the badge, a description of the scenario in which it was earned, etc.

Other badges do not: the context is in the badge description itself.

Near as I can tell, tag badges fall into this latter category... Yet the pages listing them attempt to expose one anyway, [resulting in an irritating "No longer available" placeholder](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/41/net):

[image: No longer available No longer available No longer available ...]

If there's something that would conceivably be useful or even mildly interesting, put it there - otherwise, drop the useless text.

Comment: +1 for your use of the 
calligraphy pen. It brings a classic, timeless elegance to this post

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That text will no longer be available for tag badges.

With you in the next build.

Comment: [Another one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224254/no-longer-available-on-the-list-of-users-with-research-assistant-badge) :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard - actually, looks like that is a new one (though related)

Comment: Weird, so the badge view suddenly started to show this?

Comment: @ShadowWizard - following a change elsewhere (the badge got recategorized). Pinged the dev who made the change.

Comment: Cheers, hope it would be fixed soon. (and curious to see who's that dev when he/she will fix it ;-))