# "No longer available" on the list of users with "Research Assistant" badge

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges

[image]

What does "No longer available" text on the list of users with "Research Assistant" badge mean? What's no longer available? Maybe that's the bug...

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222704/tag-badges-dont-need-a-reason

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My bad - I was doing some cleanup on why badges were awarded and Research Assistant was recategorized.

Fixed.

Comment: Mobile theme [still got this bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/311718/recently-awarded-to-no-longer-available)