# Research Assistant - user list shows "No longer available" on mobile site

Tags: bug, badges, mobile-web, edit-badges

The [list of users with the Research Assistant badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/173/research-assistant) looks 'wrong' in the mobile view.

Related question: ["No longer available" on the list of users with "Research Assistant" badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224254/no-longer-available-on-the-list-of-users-with-research-assistant-badge)

This seems to be solved in the normal website, but in the mobile view it's still shown. Also, the reputation and badges of the users aren't shown, while they are for all other badges.

[image]