# “Recently awarded to: No longer available” in mobile theme

Tags: bug, badges, mobile-web

I’m seeing something weird on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1656/research-assistant) using iOS Safari:

[image]

[Here’s](https://serverfault.com/help/badges/177/research-assistant) another link showing the same behavior.

There should be rep/badge counts, like the other badge pages I checked show:

[image]

In addition, it looks like a [similar bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/224254/323179) happened in the past, was fixed... and now this bug is happening.

Comment: The fix was done for the ordinary/full site, the mobile web use different view, which was never fixed.